# ASP.NET MVC and Web API sharing Class Library Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am going to build the following apps in .NET and I have a few questions regarding the correct architecture:

1. Console Application: read local files and update data to SQL Database in Azure
2. ASP.NET MVC: dashboard site to interact with uploaded data to SQL Database
3. Web API: handle business logic and data access.

I first thought of using Web API as the core to serving data and business logic. However, a Class Library would be needed accross the projects so that all of them "speak the same language" in terms of business objects. Example: I have a SMS object in the Console Application that will submit data to the Web API. This Web API should also have the same SMS object. Next, the ASP.NET will display SMS data, hence, should access the same object as well. But since this is an MVC app, it will have its own data object.

What would be the right approach to this?
How should be the Solution tree in Visual Studio?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use MVC, make a WebApi service, and choose a Web UI framework like react or angular. MVC is not worth using anymore.

That way, everyone connects to the WebAPI, your console app, your website/dashboard, and even a future mobile application.

IF you ever change the database from SQL server to, let's say, txt files (xD) then your console app will have to change also. Using only a single API to interact with your database will effectively separate all your layers.

> However, a Class Library would be needed across the projects so that
> all of them

Yes, but you can achieve this with a shared library or even a shared project. It's just a bunch of classes...

All your logic should be in the web API. Including the console app part. It should only do its data reads and then connect to the API.

So in this case,  you won't need to have the same model in all projects since the model for web API business model might be more complicated than the model to interact with it.

Also, serving the dashboard files to a client (browser) will be really easy, since just need to dispatch HTML, js, and CSS files. Any server will do and also it won't be tied to .Net or any serverside code you like.

[image]

Comment: It all makes sense to me now. Having Web UI like Angular instead of MVC is perhaps the most modern solution nowadays. Still, for the backend piece, would you have a shared class library project across Console App, Dashboard and Web API so that it acts like a "contract"?

Comment: No. I wouldnt. Normally webapi might have complicated stuff that is not necessarily on the API per-se, ie, the contract.
Dashboard and console app are going to be made in different languages probably: Console App in C# for example and dashboard in javascript.

I understand that COnsole app and WebApi are going to have the same basic shared models, And you might share it, but only the contract one, not the business layer one. And that wont make sense anymore.

Comment: Sorry i pressed enter while typing and send comment before finished.

Comment: I think you were able to realize that I am an old school developer trying to catch up on today's technology =)
Maybe this question deserves a new topic but what are the best practices to build Web API in terms of architecture? I see you mentioned bussiness layer so I assume there are stardands to do it.

Comment: I know your feeling, I just jumped from WebForms to Angular2 xD. I never liked MVC on web applications. And yes of course, i pretty much like Rest Apis: http://rest.elkstein.org
Now, PERSONALLY, i moved all logic to database (if relational) or services/tasks (if nosql), so i have a very thin API which only handles requests, auth, and replies back to client. And then in the client, all UI stuff are done in js. On WebAPI and APP there is only data flowing between them. If its a website, html and files are served from diferent website/area/server to keep layers apart.

Comment: " Now, PERSONALLY, i moved all logic to database " - you just spread controversy into the world now =)

This makes me remember my early days developing stored procedures on SQL Server 7 to handle business logic.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean that because it's an MVC application it needs to have its own data object.What I've done in the past was to create a class library and add references to the MVC related DLLs to this project.Then I would decorate the objects with all the required MVC attributes and finally I would add a reference to this class library to all the projects in my application that require them like Business Layer,Web api layer and the MVC(UI) layer.

In your scenario it could be something like this:

[image: Common object library]

Comment: This is what I thought at first, just wasn't sure if Class Library was the right type of project to support this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to comment on this answer. While it is a valid one, its not the best solution.
For example, why would you want an API if your MVC and the rest of applications wont consume it?

Comment: The MVC will consume the API.The diagram above is merely to illustrate the relationship between the common object library and the rest of the projects in the solution